# How to Get a List of Formats of a Block?

Tags: block-editor

StackExchange Community,

I have created a custom format using the Format API. I need a way of retrieving a list of formats being used on the currently selected block. Basically it needs to behave similarly to `getActiveFormat( value, formatName )`. The primary difference being that this function only retrieves the format instance of the selected text. I need a list of every instance of my custom format as the custom formats will have unique attributes that will be added when applying the custom format. For example I am looking to do the following.

```
const currentBlock = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock()
const formats = getActiveFormats( currentBlock )

console.log(formats)

// Expecting to log a current list of all format instances as objects
```

If you have created functions before it would generate a list similar to the `value.formats` property that is passed through the edit. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Additional context**

Below is an example of how I am adding a the new format. Basically, the format is adding a link to a post that will be used to trigger a modal view of the post. The value object has a property called formats which contains an updated list of formats used on the block. I then use render_block to inject my modal html based on what posts are specified via the format. If I could parse a list of my custom format instances to the block attribute, this should work. The problem I am having is applying the format and then updating the block attribute using the onChange function that is passed into the edit props.

```
import { 
    registerFormatType, 
    getActiveFormat, 
    getActiveFormats, 
    useAnchorRef 
} from '@wordpress/rich-text';

import { default as ModalPopover } from './components/modal-popover';

const formatName = 'custom-format/modal-text-link';

function ModalEdit( props ) {
    const {
        name,
        activeAttributes,
        activeObjectAttributes,
        value,
        onChange,
        contentRef,
    } = props

    // ...removed for simplicity

    console.log( value.formats );
    // returns a current list of all formats on this block

    return (
        <>
            <RichTextToolbarButton
                icon={ <Icon size="36px" icon={ inbox } /> }
                title="Modal Link"
                onClick={ openModal }
                isActive={ isActive() }
            />
            { isOpen && (
                <ModalPopover
                    name={ formatName }
                    value={ value }
                    onClose={ closeModal }
                    onChange={ ( ...args ) => onChange( ...args ) }
                    isFormat={ true }
                    anchorRef={ anchorRef }
                    changeAttribute={ changeAttribute }
                />
            ) }
        </>
    );
}
registerFormatType( formatName, {
    title: 'Modal Text Link',
    tagName: 'a',
    className: 'modal-text-link',
    edit: ModalEdit,
} );
```

Comment: What does your custom format do? It seems quite involved. Note that blocks themselves don't have formats, only richtext values and components. Context will help enormously here, especially given that some solutions to this may lead to infinite recursion and other problems. What's the problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the response, here is some context with what I am doing. I have a custom format that requires the selection of a post. Similar to the built-in link format that requires a url to be entered into the popover, I have a popover with a select input. The selector is a list of posts. The selected option will be added using a html data attribute in the span tag. For example `<span data-post-id="332">`. I need this to add content based on the selection using the `render_block` hook. Only problem is that it only sees the blocks attributes (not the formats) for the reason you mentioned above.

Comment: So my goal is to be able to detect all instances of my custom format and pass it to its "parent" block as an array. Alternatively, if it all possible maybe some how retrieve all formats applied on the block content so I can parse out custom format values but the former would be ideal.

Comment: that's because formats don't exist as an entity, the end result is just tags in HTML. Formats are just a way to make that easier, possibly even add UI, but the end result is always just tags. I believe chasing after detecting formats is the wrong approach, as it assumes there's a list of formats that is added and removed. This is not the case. If you ask for a list of formats in text, it will parse the text and figure out the formats as it goes. Just search the HTML for your data attributes.

Comment: I also suspect that formats should never have been used to begin with, but I can't advise on that with just the context you've provided. What you've shared is too generic and I can't identify the purpose and what it is you're trying to build by doing this. What exactly is the `render_block` hook doing? Is this an elaborate scheme to get inline embedding of post content?

Comment: Also which language/where in your code are you trying to get this information? Your question is worded to imply you're doing this inside a blocks javascript

Comment: @TomJNowell I updated the post above. I am hoping that has enough details to show what I am doing here. The goal is to apply modal links to text. The modals are obviously created as CPTs and are options in the Popover. So yes, I am trying to embed post content as modals and have the ability to apply these links onto text. I am in javascript above but I am using render_block in PHP to inject the modal(s) based on what is requested. This is why I am trying to pass the array of modal ids to the block attribute so I can use this in the hook.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid searching the HTML if possible as it seemed cleaner and more efficient to have it available as an array in the block attributes. This however was based on my assumption that there might be a simple way of generating a list of formats on the block similar to however `value.formats` is constructed.

Comment: Ah that's very useful to know. There may even be a way to integrate it into the link format so you can reuse the existing options but add a checkbox to open in a modal. Then something like '$('a[data-modal=true]')` in jQuery would be enough to find them. Just know that searching the HTML is exactly what the formatting library is doing